# What would be the best way to write repetitive code like this?

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code, which opens up a Monarch instance, and does some actions with Monarch (Monarch is a datamining tool)

I have to repeat the below code, simply changing a few parameters each time, is there a way to programatically do this? I want to know the most effeicent way of doing this.

```
a = MonarchObj.SetReportFile(rawdataS10, False)
openModel = MonarchObj.SetModelFile(freeKidsModel)
            MonarchObj.CurrentFilter = "Under 60"


    SummerDateShow = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date2", False)
    SummerDateHide = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date", True)

ExportTOS = MonarchObj.JetExportTable(saveDir, "FreeKidsS10", 0)
MonarchObj.CloseAllDocuments
```

An example of the parts i'm changing are "Under 60" "FreeKidsS10" and the Date & Date2 fields.

If simply copy and pasting this code is the most effecient code, you can tell me to go away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a procedure that takes as parameters the variable fields and then call that procedure wherever you would otherwise copy and paste. The signature of that method would be something like this:

```
    Public Sub DataMiningMethod(ByVal modelFile as object, _
                                ByVal currentFilter as String, _ 
                                ByVal date1 as Boolean, _
                                ByVal date2 as Boolean, _
                                ByVal exportTableName as String)
```

Thus the entire method would look something like this:

```
Public Sub DataMiningMethod(ByVal modelFile as object, _
                            ByVal currentFilter as String, _ 
                            ByVal date1 as Boolean, _
                            ByVal date2 as Boolean, _
                            ByVal exportTableName as String)

    a = MonarchObj.SetReportFile(rawdataS10, False)
    openModel = MonarchObj.SetModelFile(modelFile )
            MonarchObj.CurrentFilter = currentFilter 


    SummerDateShow = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date2", date2 )
    SummerDateHide = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date", date1 )

    ExportTOS = MonarchObj.JetExportTable(saveDir, exportTableName , 0)
    MonarchObj.CloseAllDocuments

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user defined function - there are many examples on google - here is one -

http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a method and if you want to be more precise put in a class and class it with differ parameters each time like

```
public void mymethod(string currentFilter, bool date2, bool date)
{
 a = MonarchObj.SetReportFile(rawdataS10, False)
 openModel = MonarchObj.SetModelFile(freeKidsModel)
 MonarchObj.CurrentFilter = currentFilter


 SummerDateShow = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date2", date2)
 SummerDateHide = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible("Date", date)

 ExportTOS = MonarchObj.JetExportTable(saveDir, "FreeKidsS10", 0)
 MonarchObj.CloseAllDocuments
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Excel. You can try using another sheet with data and making this methods getting each line at a time,something like:

```
      A           B           C       D
1 Under60    FreeKidsS10    Date    Date2
2 Under80    FreeKidsS20    DateZ   Date3
3 Over80     FreeKidsS30    DateX   Date4
```

and you change you macro to use something like:

```
a = MonarchObj.SetReportFile(rawdataS10, False)
openModel = MonarchObj.SetModelFile(freeKidsModel)
        MonarchObj.CurrentFilter = 'Sheet2!$A1'


SummerDateShow = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible('Sheet2!$D1', False)
SummerDateHide = MonarchObj.SetFieldVisible('Sheet2!$C1', True)

ExportTOS = MonarchObj.JetExportTable(saveDir, 'Sheet2!$B1', 0)
MonarchObj.CloseAllDocuments
```

I am not sure on the exact code, but I thing you can go along this line to reach necessary target